# Is using Apple products abroad as simple as just replacing the plug on the AC adapter?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, charging, power, magsafe

For many Apple products, e.g. MacBook Air, or iPhone, the power supply is the same for different countries, and it accepts a power range of 100-240V and 50-60H (which I think is a great idea, since it encompasses most of the power standard used around the world; I don’t know whether this is specific to Apple or common practice).

Does this mean that the only item which is different is the actual, phsyical plug piece, i.e. the piece which connects the adapter to the plug (note that this piece is actually the same for different adapters, namely different W)?

Is it then possible to just buy that piece (it shouldn't cost more than a few $$$) such that it has the desired shape, compatible to the country of interest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple [sells](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB974ZM/B/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit?fnode=efcfc1bf8b00666a82d841704d8374b3a6457b9bbed36842c7c1bb4db9edefc06a56e34d65b285c986ab533a9ffc73cbde28ddd11045f5b4ffe1cee36b8581fb89ac8bb9e8dfce4fee8b992cd51b728373f3d51d81a68479d2a4135a8101cebb7c0483c6cdffb095aa1eb1869d1c71ba) a "world traveler kit" which is effectively the plug bit for their chargers, so that would be a definite yes.